# linq nested select in Contains method

Tags: c#, sql, linq, select, nested

Can this be converted to a single LINQ statement?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Abstract_Dedications_Lookup 
WHERE PlatEntryNumber = 10383772 
AND CommonArea = 0 
AND ((OuterType <> '' AND OuterValue <> '') OR (InnerType <> '' AND InnerValue <> '')) 
AND ParcelNumber IN 
(SELECT ParentParcelNumber 
FROM Parcel_Title_History 
WHERE EntryNumber <> 10383772 
AND ParentParcelNumber <> '0' 
AND ChildParcelNumber <> ParentParcelNumber)
```

I have tried many variations and can not get the correct syntax in the ".Contains" method. Can a "SELECT" be used within the "Contains"?

```
var query2 = from d in context.RTV_ParcelDedicationLocations
from p in context.RTV_ParcelTitleHistory
where d.PlatEntryNumber == PlatEntryNum
where d.CommonArea == false
where (d.OuterType != "" && d.OuterValue != "") || (d.InnerType != "" && d.InnerValue != "")
where d.ParcelNumber.Contains(p.ChildParcelNumber != p.ParentParcelNumber)
select d;                      
var results2 = query2.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate linq statements that will get executed by the database as 1 query. A linq statement dosent actually get execute until you begin to iterate over it.

The way I thought about this problem was to define a query that gets valid ParentParcelNumber from Parcel_Title_History. Then create another query that checks if the items in Abstract_Dedications_Lookup are in the first query. Try something like this:

```
var query1 =  from p in context.RTV_ParcelTitleHistory
                where p.EntryNumber != 10383772 & p.ParentParcelNumber != "0" & p.ChildParcelNumber != p.ParentParcelNumber
                select p.ParentParcelNumber;

var query2 = from d in context.RTV_ParcelDedicationLocations
                where d.PlatEntryNumber == 10383772
                & d.CommonArea == 0
                & ((d.OuterType != "" && d.OuterValue != "") || (d.InnerType != "" && d.InnerValue != ""))
                & query1.Contains(d.ParcelNumber)
                select d;

var results2 = query2.ToList();
```

Comment: The logic is correct and it runs so that gets me on the right track. I have an an out_of_memory exception, probably because the result count from the ParcelTitleHistory query has approx 300,000 records and the Contains on that large result set chews up lots of memory.

Comment: query1 wouldnt actually return 300,000 rows, it would create WHERE IN (SELECT...) type query like in your OP. What is the count you get from query2.Count()? EDIT: Actually I assumed you were using Entity Framework, if that is not the case, then yes, query1 is returning 300,000 rows.

Comment: Count from query2 is 43,909. True that the code as is above doesn't return a count. I added it to get an idea of how many records were coming back from query1 and then removed it. Compared to the SQL from the OP, the count from query2 should be 185. Yes, I am using EF.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the "out_of_memory" exception was caused by an extra "from" clause that I accidentally added from a previous attempt at the query. I removed that and no more memory exception but the count from query2 is still incorrect.

Comment: Hmm, thats way off. Can you write out query2.ToTraceString() and compare with query in OP?

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ generated SQL statement below returns 44,092 records but should be same as the SQL in the OP which returns 182 records. Something in the query2 LINQ isn't correct apparently:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ParcelNumber] AS [ParcelNumber], 
[Extent1].[PlatEntryNumber] AS [PlatEntryNumber], 
[Extent1].[OuterType] AS [OuterType], 
[Extent1].[OuterValue] AS [OuterValue], 
[Extent1].[InnerType] AS [InnerType], 
[Extent1].[InnerValue] AS [InnerValue], 
[Extent1].[CommonArea] AS [CommonArea]
FROM (SELECT 
[RTV_ParcelDedicationLocations].[ParcelNumber] AS [ParcelNumber], 
[RTV_ParcelDedicationLocations].[PlatEntryNumber] AS [PlatEntryNumber], 
[RTV_ParcelDedicationLocations].[OuterType] AS [OuterType], 
[RTV_ParcelDedicationLocations].[OuterValue] AS [OuterValue], 
[RTV_ParcelDedicationLocations].[InnerType] AS [InnerType], 
[RTV_ParcelDedicationLocations].[InnerValue] AS [InnerValue], 
[RTV_ParcelDedicationLocations].[CommonArea] AS [CommonArea]
FROM [dbo].[RTV_ParcelDedicationLocations] AS [RTV_ParcelDedicationLocations]) AS [Extent1]
WHERE (([Extent1].[PlatEntryNumber] = 10383772) AND (10383772 IS NOT NULL) 
AND (0 = [Extent1].[CommonArea]) AND ('''' <> [Extent1].[OuterType]) AND ('''' <> [Extent1].[OuterValue])) 
OR (('''' <> [Extent1].[InnerType]) AND ('''' <> [Extent1].[InnerValue])
AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS [C1]
FROM (SELECT  [RTV_ParcelTitleHistory].[EntryNumber] AS [EntryNumber], 
[RTV_ParcelTitleHistory].[ParentParcelNumber] AS [ParentParcelNumber], 
[RTV_ParcelTitleHistory].[ChildParcelNumber] AS [ChildParcelNumber], 
[RTV_ParcelTitleHistory].[Book] AS [Book], 
[RTV_ParcelTitleHistory].[Page] AS [Page]
FROM [dbo].[RTV_ParcelTitleHistory] AS [RTV_ParcelTitleHistory]) AS [Extent2]
WHERE ( NOT (([Extent2].[EntryNumber] = 10383772) AND (10383772 IS NOT NULL))) AND ('0' <> [Extent2].[ParentParcelNumber]) AND ([Extent2].[ChildParcelNumber] <> [Extent2].[ParentParcelNumber]) AND ([Extent2].[ParentParcelNumber] = [Extent1].[ParcelNumber])
)))
```